# Events Firing Out Of Order Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net-2.0

I have a system setup as follows:

User Control Called "Main" when I click a button in "Main" another user control (user control "A", user control "B", user control "C") is populated inside a placeholder of "Main" depending on some logic either A,B, or C is populated.

User controls A,B,C have many buttons on them as well. They Also have a placeholder to contain either user control x, user control y, user control z depending what is clicked inside user control "A" for example.

Main loads controls (A,B, or C) into its placeholder no problem, but when I click a button in A,B,or C to load their placeholder with x,y, or z the whole control (A,B, or C) dissappears.

I understand this has to do with viewstate not holding dynamic controls during a postback. So what I did was explictly called viewstate on the controls loaded into main (A,B,C). when they are loaded I save an entry of what was loaded like this ViewState("lastLoaded")='A' for example. When a postabck occurs (i.e. clicking a button in A) I reload the whole control A.

This is what happens:
I click a button in user control "A" 
Postback occurs
User control "A" is reloaded because of the viewstate("lastloaded")
Then I have to click the button in "A" again at that time the button_click event fires

Can someone please help me fix this.

'Here is Main.ascx

Partial Class Main 
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
    ViewState("name") = "ControlA2.ascx" 
    AddControl(ViewState("name").ToString()) 
End Sub 

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load 
    If ViewState("name") <> String.Empty Then 
        AddControl(ViewState("name").ToString()) 

    End If 
End Sub 

Public Sub AddControl(ByVal name As String) 
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear() 
    Dim toAdd As Control = LoadControl(name) 
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(toAdd) 
End Sub 

Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click 
    ViewState("name") = "ControlB.ascx" 
    AddControl(ViewState("name").ToString()) 
End Sub
```

End Class

'Here is Main designer

```
Main
```

asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add Control A" 
  
asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Add Control B"

asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server">

'Here is ControlA2.ascx

Partial Class ControlA2 
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear() 
    Dim toAdd As Control = LoadControl("ControlX.ascx") 
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(toAdd) 
End Sub
```

End Class

'Here is ControlA2 designer

```
I am Control A

Add Control X 
asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add Control X"
```

asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"
/asp:PlaceHolder

'Here is ControlB.ascx 
Partial Class ControlA2 
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear() 
    Dim toAdd As Control = LoadControl("ControlZ.ascx") 
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(toAdd) 
End Sub
```

End Class

'Here is ControlB designer

```
I am Control B 

Add Control Z
```

asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add Control Z"

asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" /asp:PlaceHolder

'Here is ControlX.designer

```
asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label">I AM CONTROL X  /asp:Label
```

'Here is ControlZ designer

```
asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label">I AM CONTROL Z /asp:Label
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant pieces of your code?

Comment: Can I attach a sample project on here?

Comment: Here is a sample of what I am trying to accomplish...If someone could make this work that would fix my problem. 

I am going to post a sample that has Main.ascx, ControlA.ascx, ControlB.ascx, ControlX.ascx, ControlZ.ascx

Comment: Main.ascx 
<p>
    Main</p>
<p>
    &nbsp;</p>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add Control A" />
&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Add Control B" />
<br />
<br />
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>

Comment: I cant place any code in here not enough room

Comment: You should be able to edit your original question.

Comment: Is there anyway I can post a small sample project on here? I recreated the problem to see if anyone can figure it out.

Comment: Andy I tried your code but now the button click events in ControlA nor in ControlB fire at all. The controls must be reloaded on every postback otherwise the controls will dissappear so you must reload the control onto the the main control (which is on the default page) everytime any button is click on any control. The trick to this is letting viewstate know that AFTER the postback occurs and the control is reloaded is to automatically fire the event that raised the postback. This I have no idea how I can do?

Answer (score 0):

I've created a project based on your code and I've managed to recreate the issue.
When I initially run it and click on the Add control A button the Main control will load Control A and note this in the viewstate. Control A's button to add Control X will now appear with an id of **Main1_ctl00_Button1**. When clicking on this button Main's page load will add Control A back to it's placeholder and Control A's button click event will fire. If you now click Main's Control A button again the problem arises. Main's page load method will look at the Viewstate and add control A to the placeholder. Then Main's button click event will then fire clearing the placeholder and re-adding control A. When the form is displayed Control A's button to add Control X will now have an id of **Main1_ctl01_Button1** as it was the second control to be generated in the code behind. Now when you click on the button to add control x Main's page load will add Control A again but as it's id will be Main1_ctl00_Button1 and the click event came from a button with an id of Main1_ctl01_Button1 the event will not fire.

To fix this you will have to avoid the duplication of control creation the second time around. You could do this by checking the requests form collection during the page load to see which button was pressed although this is not a very elegant solution. You will need to ensure that the buttons on the Main control have a unique text value for this to work. 
Hopefully someone else may be able to come up with a more elegant solution:

```
Dim mainButtonClick = False
For index As Integer = 0 To Request.Form.Count
    If Request.Form(index) = "Button A" Or Request.Form(index) = "Button B" Then
        mainButtonClick = True
    End If
Next

If Not IsPostBack And Not mainButtonClick And ViewState("name") <> String.Empty Then
    AddControl(ViewState("name").ToString())
End If
```

Please excuse any errors in this code as I am not a VB.NET programmer.

Comment: Andy I added code. If you could create a samll project ot make make this mechism work. This will fix my problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: This Answer will reload the control, but the problem still remains there. Could someone please take a look at my sample code of the problem and try to fix it. I cannot figure this one out :0 Thanks in advance

Comment: If I do not create the control it will disappear all together during postback. How do I fix it? Can you give me some code? Ive been going 12 hours straight on this thing.

Comment: It behaves like the following....
1. Control is loaded into main control
2. A button is clicked inside the Control
3. A page wide post occurs
4. Viewstate("name") holds the data to repopulate the the control and does successfully put the control back into main again
5. Now if I click the button in the control it the click event fires and works

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue your having is with the id's asp.net is dynamically creating for your controls. I would suggest viewing the source of each page between postbacks to check the user contol ids specifically the ctlxx part.

Comment: Is it possible for you to write code to fix the the problem in the example. I agree it must have to do with the id's asp.net is creating but I am uncertain how to programmatically fix this problem.